# How to avoid N+1 in this situation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, eager-loading

I'm trying to implement a "liking" system in my app. I render a table with orders, then the current user is able to "like" an order so she will get notifications when the status of the order changes. The problem is that I'm in an N+1 issue, since each time the table gets rendered, the program makes as many queries as orders are displayed to detect if an order has already been "liked" by the user.

I have read that this can be avoided by using "includes" to eager load the associated records, but I can't wrap my head around how to do it, particularly in my case.

I have these models and associations:

`user.rb` Did I include the likes? the method which is triggering the N+1 alert:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, 
  :validatable
  has_many :likes

  def likes?(order)
    order.likes.where(user_id: id).any?
  end
end
```

`like.rb`

```
class Like < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :order
end
```

`order.rb`

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord

 has_many :likes
 .
 .
 .
```

For each row of the table I render this partial to show if the order is liked or not:

```
<% if current_user.likes?(order) %>
  <%= link_to "<i class='fa fa-fire fa-2x fa-like'></i>".html_safe, 
  order_like_path(order), method: :delete, remote: true %>
<%else%>
  <%= link_to "<i class='fa fa-fire fa-2x fa-unlike'></i>".html_safe, 
  order_like_path(order), method: :post, remote: true %>
<%end%>
```

This is the query:

```
Rendered orders/_likes.html.erb (135.5ms)
Like Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "likes" WHERE "likes"."order_id" 
=$1 AND "likes"."user_id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["order_id", 7875], ["user_id", 
1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

EDIT. I add the index action in case it is useful:

```
  def index
    orders = request.query_string.present? ? Order.search(params, 
    current_user) : Order.pendientes
    if params[:button] == 'report'
      build_report(orders)
    else
    @orders = orders.order("#{sort_column} # 
    {sort_direction}").page(params[:page]).per(params[:paginas])
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :likes

  has_many :liked_orders, through: :likes, class_name: 'Order'

  def liked_orders_id
    @liked_orders_id ||= liked_orders.pluck(:id)
  end

  def liked_order?(order_id)
    liked_orders_id.include?(order_id)
  end
end
```

The root cause behind your problem to me seems to be in the way you have implemented the `likes?(order)` method in `User` model

```
  def likes?(order)
    order.likes.where(user_id: id).any?
  end
```

Every-time you invoke this method on a loaded `User`, it first loads `Order` instance, then on that loaded Order, loads its associated `Like` instances and on those loaded `Like` instances applies the `user_id` filter.

**Update**

The `liked_orders` association should be defined as

```
  has_many :liked_orders, through: :likes, source: :order
```

Comment: I get this error trying to implement your solution: `Could not find the association :likes in model User`

Comment: That's an association setup error. In your original post you have shown `has_many :likes` in User model. If that is present then the error you have reported should not occur.

Comment: Right sorry, I had wrongly removed `has_many :likes`. Now I get this error message: `ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError - Could not find the source association(s) "liked_order" or :liked_o      rders in model Like. Try 'has_many :liked_orders, :through => :likes, :source => <name>'. Is it one of user or order?:
`

Comment: That's straight enough to try out. Use source as `:order`. For more details please refer the guide at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-has-many-source

Comment: Worked! he N+1 query dissappeared. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

What generally I do in this situation is that as you have the `orders` already on the view and you have the `user` so I fetch:

```
likes = current_user.likes.where(order: orders)
liked_order_ids = likes.pluck(:order_id)
```

And I will pass the `liked_order_ids` each time to the `_likes` partial and check `liked_order_ids.include?(order.id)`

I have not fetched the `user.likes` directly because there may be many `orders` he has liked and all are not present on the current page. If they are you can fetch them directly like this:

```
liked_order_ids = current_user.likes.pluck(:order_id)
```

So this way it will not execute any new queries or cached queries too.

The way you are trying to do is search in the `order` likes, so going through `order` object. Instead you have the `user` through which you can find the `likes` as it `belongs to` him too. As `order` will always be multiple and `user` will be single it will execute a single query to find it instead of searching multiple times in database using `order`.

Obviously there are many more ways around it. The choice will depend on you and your situation.

Comment: `collect(&:order_id)` shouldn't it be `pluck(:order_id)`?

Comment: `pluck(&:order_id) != pluck(:order_id)` :)

Comment: I tried this as well, the solution works perfectly to fix the N+1 query but it was more complex to deal with lthe variables to pass them thrugh the different controller and views (likes#create, likes#delete, the diffreent partials etc) so I'm going to accept @Jiggneshh Gohel answer

Answer (score 0):

It is in the OrdersController show or index action, right? You need to redefine instance variable like this:

```
@orders = current_user.orders.includes(:likes)
or 
@order = current_user.orders.find(params[:id]).includes(:likes)
```

And move `likes?` method to the Order model (change it `liked_by` for example).

```
def liked_by?(user)
  likes.where(user_id: user.id).exists?
end
```

In the view you'll have

```
<% if order.liked_by?(current_user) %>
```

In this case likes will be preloaded and you avoid N+1 issue.

It is a good idea to add [bullet](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet) gem to the app, it will warn you about N+1 queries and give suggestions about `includes`

UPDATE:

Just add `includes` to the existing @orders

```
@orders = orders.includes(:likes).order("#{sort_column} # 
    {sort_direction}").page(params[:page]).per(params[:paginas])
```

Comment: Yes, it is in the index action, the problem is that the orders don't belong to the user, so I think can't redefine the instance variables as you propose. I have added the index action snippet to clarify.

Comment: Still triggers N+1 query